# jtable not showing data in jsp it show error

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets, jquery-jtable

i am here tired to show data in JTable in jsp but it always showing error in dialgoue box like **"An error occured while communicating to the server."**
i am new to ajax jquery how to show data to this kindly help on this???

html:

```
<!-- Include one of jTable styles. -->
<link href="blue/jtable.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="js/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<!-- Include jTable script file. -->
<!-- Include jTable script file. -->


<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jtable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">



    $(document).ready(function() {



        $('#test').jtable({
                title : 'Senthil Table List',
           paging: true, //Enable paging
           pageSize: 20, //Set page size (default: 10)          
           actions: 
           {
               listAction: 'Form?action=listUser',
            /*    createAction:'Form?action=insert',
               updateAction: 'Form?action=edit',
               deleteAction: 'Form?action=delete' */
           },

               fields : {
                        Id : {
                                title : 'Id',
                                sort :true,
                                width : '30%',
                                key : true,
                                list : true,
                                edit : false,
                                create : true
                        },
                        Name : {
                                title : 'Name',
                                width : '30%',
                                edit : true
                        },
                        Job : {
                                title : 'Job',
                                width : '30%',
                                edit : true
                        },

                }
        });
        $('#test').jtable('load');
});


<script>
</head>
<body>


<div id="test">
</div>
```

Servlet:

```
package Servlet;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;



import org.json.JSONObject;

import Allmethod.Testmethod;
import DAO.Dao;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Form
 */
@WebServlet("/Form")
public class Form extends HttpServlet 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */



    private static String INSERT_OR_EDIT = "/Edit.jsp";
    private static String LIST_USER = "/listUser.jsp";



    private Testmethod t;
    Dao dao=new Dao();
    public Form() 
    {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        t=new Testmethod();
    }
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        response.setContentType("application/Json");


        System.out.println("inside form");
        try
        {
        String forward="";
        String action = request.getParameter("action");

        System.out.println("action are========>"+action);
 if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("listUser")) 
        {
        try 
        {
            forward = LIST_USER;
            System.out.println("inside========");

                // Fetch Data from Student Table
               Object s = t.Select(1, 10);
                // Get Total Record Count for Pagination
                int userCount = t.getStudentCount();
                // Convert Java Object to Json



                String jsonvalue="";


               JSONObject obj1=new JSONObject();
             obj1.put("users", s);
            String resp = jsonvalue+"("+obj1.toString()+"TotalRecordCount"+  userCount + ")";

            System.out.println("response are====>"+resp);

        response.getWriter().print(resp);


         System.out.println("forward====>"+forward);
         RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(forward);
         view.forward(request, response);


        }
                catch(Exception ex)
        {
                        String error="{\"Result\":\"ERROR\",\"Message\":"+ex.getMessage()+"}";
                        response.getWriter().print(error);
        }
        }

        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

**java class:**

public List<Dao> Select(int startPageIndex, int recordsPerPage) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException 
    {
            List<Dao> daos = new ArrayList<Dao>();
            int range = startPageIndex+recordsPerPage;
            String query="SELECT *  from senthiil Limit "+startPageIndex+","+recordsPerPage+"";
          //  System.out.println(query);

            con=databases.getconnection();
            try 
            {
                PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(query);

                System.out.println("ps====xxx======>"+ps);
                ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
                while(rs.next())
                {
                    Dao dao=new Dao();

                    dao.setId(rs.getInt(1));
                    dao.setName(rs.getString(2));
                    dao.setJob(rs.getString(3));

                    System.out.println("dao========>"+dao);
                    daos.add(dao);
                }

            } 
            catch (SQLException e) 
            {
                    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            return daos;
    }

**My response are**

    response are====>({"users":["Dao [id=145, name=ammudha, job=appa]","Dao [id=146, name=sgfs, job=sdfsd]","Dao [id=147, name=null, job=null]","Dao [id=148, name=null, job=null]","Dao [id=149, name=null, job=null]","Dao [id=150, name=null, job=null]","Dao [id=151, name=null, job=null]","Dao [id=152, name=null, job=null]","Dao [id=153, name=null, job=null]","Dao [id=154, name=null, job=null]"]}TotalRecordCount51)
```

data are coming from servlet but while jsp loading to error occured

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the solution, you can change the way you invoke the action.

Something like this:

```
$('#test').jtable({
            title : 'Senthil Table List',
       paging: true, //Enable paging
       pageSize: 20, //Set page size (default: 10)          
       actions: 
       {
           listAction: function (postData, jtParams) {
                return $.Deferred(function ($dfd) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'Form?action=listUser',
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: postData,
                        success: function (data) {
                            $dfd.resolve(data);
                        },
                        error: function (request, status, error) {
                            $dfd.reject();
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
       },

           fields : {
                    Id : {
                            title : 'Id',
                            sort :true,
                            width : '30%',
                            key : true,
                            list : true,
                            edit : false,
                            create : true
                    },
                    Name : {
                            title : 'Name',
                            width : '30%',
                            edit : true
                    },
                    Job : {
                            title : 'Job',
                            width : '30%',
                            edit : true
                    },

            }
    });
    $('#test').jtable('load');
```

Then, you can debug in Chrome or other browser, review the object "error" in the error function and find the problem.